# How to convert 2d array-list to two dimintion string array in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, type-2-dimension

can you help me please
I have a quiz application and i get the questions and answers from database ..answers must put in two diminution string array .. i am adding them first in an array-list by for loop .. and then i have to convert this array-list to string array .. and this is the problem .. i am getting this exception

java.lang.ArrayStoreException: source[0] of type java.util.ArrayList cannot be stored in destination array of type java.lang.String[][]

```
package com.example.asd.cloudproject;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.kosalgeek.asynctask.AsyncResponse;
import com.kosalgeek.asynctask.PostResponseAsyncTask;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;


public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse {
   // private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();

    private TextView mScoreView;
    private TextView mQuestionView;
    private Button mButtonChoice1;
    private Button mButtonChoice2;
    private Button mButtonChoice3;

    private String mAnswer;
    private int mScore = 0;
    private int mQuestionNumber = 0;
    String username;
    String password;
    UserSessionManager session;
    private String mChoices [][];
    private String mQuestions [];
    private String mCorrectAnswers[];
    ArrayList<String> quetionArrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> answerArrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> correctArrayList= new ArrayList<String>();
    //List<String[]> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
    ArrayList<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>(); // added ()

    @Override

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);
        mScoreView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.score);
        mQuestionView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.question);
        mButtonChoice1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mButtonChoice2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mButtonChoice3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.choice3);

        //check user login
        session =new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());
        if (session.checkLogin())
            finish();

        HashMap<String,String> user =session.getUserDetails();
        username=user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_NAME);
        password=user.get(UserSessionManager.KEY_PASSWORD);

        HashMap postdata=new HashMap();
        postdata.put("user_name",username);
        postdata.put("password",password);

        PostResponseAsyncTask task=new PostResponseAsyncTask(this,postdata);
        task.execute("http://10.0.2.2/quiz.php");

     //   updateQuestion();

        //Start of Button Listener for Button1
        mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer){
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    //This line of code is optiona
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();
                }
            }
        });

        //End of Button Listener for Button1

        //Start of Button Listener for Button2
        mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer){
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    //This line of code is optiona
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();
                }
            }
        });

        //End of Button Listener for Button2


        //Start of Button Listener for Button3
        mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer){
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();
                    //This line of code is optiona
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateQuestion();
                }
            }
        });

        //End of Button Listener for Button3





    }

    private void updateQuestion(){
        mQuestionView.setText(getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice1.setText(getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice2.setText(getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
        mButtonChoice3.setText(getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));

        mAnswer = getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
        mQuestionNumber++;
    }


    private void updateScore(int point) {
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);
    }


    ///////////////////////////////////////


    @Override
    public void processFinish(String s) {
        String[] separated = s.split("#");
        int i =separated.length;
        String[] items;
        String[] answers;
       // String[][] Choices = new String[0][];

        // String[] separated = s.split("$");
        //Integer COUNT = stringArrayList.size();
        for (int t = 0; t <i; t++) {
            items=separated[t].split(":");

           String vquestion=items[0].toString();
           String vanswer=items[1].toString();
           String vcorrect=items[2].toString();

            quetionArrayList.add(vquestion);
            answerArrayList.add(vanswer);
            correctArrayList.add(vcorrect);

        }


        int y=answerArrayList.size();
        String[] ans = new String[y];
        ans = answerArrayList.toArray(ans);
        ///////////
        mQuestions =new String[quetionArrayList.size()];
        mQuestions = quetionArrayList.toArray(mQuestions);
        mCorrectAnswers=new String[correctArrayList.size()];
        mCorrectAnswers = correctArrayList.toArray(mCorrectAnswers);
////////////////////////
        for(int x=0 ; x<y ; x++){
            answers=ans[x].split("&");
            temp.add(answers[0]);
            temp.add(answers[1]);
            temp.add(answers[2]);
            temp.add(answers[3]);
            listOfLists.add(temp);
            temp.clear();

        }
          ///// here is the problem //////
          mChoices  = new String[4][listOfLists.size()];
          mChoices = listOfLists.toArray(mChoices);
        //String ch =mChoices[2][1].toString();


    }

    public String getQuestion(int a) {
        String question = mQuestions[a];
        return question;
    }


    public String getChoice1(int a) {
        String choice0 = mChoices[a][0];
        return choice0;
    }


    public String getChoice2(int a) {
        String choice1 = mChoices[a][1];
        return choice1;
    }

    public String getChoice3(int a) {
        String choice2 =mChoices[a][2];
        return choice2;
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
        String answer = mCorrectAnswers[a];
        return answer;
    }


}
```

Comment: I usually find that running the code in a debugger and looking at the different array elements during runtime is helpful in understanding how to solve these kind of problems. You are probably trying to store an array in a non-array variable.

Comment: Could you provide an example showing input and output?

Comment: mChoices = listOfLists.toArray(mChoices);
this line mean that i want to convert two dimintion arraylist called (listOfLists) to a string array like a table have two dimintion too ..

Comment: Did you look for any solutions? https://www.google.com/search?q=java+convert+two+dimensional+list+to+array

Comment: I tried all of these solutions .. it is not work